# Google Tag Manager with angular js links

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, angular-ui-router, google-tag-manager

I some links in my application which I want to track the click on those links with the help of GTM. Imagine I have a link to download page like this

```
<a ui-sref="main.download">Download</a>
```

I create a tag of type 'Universial Google Analytics' for this click named `MainDownloadLink`.

How should I define a trigger to fire this tag when that link is clicked? Also note that I don't want to use `angularitics` library. Imagine that I have no control over the source code. just GTM panel.

I define a trigger of type `Clicks-Just Link` and I am confused for the condition when this event should be fired.

any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make sure that "link validation" is disabled (since GTM does not consider links without href to be valid).

As long as your links are actually named "Download" it probably would be easiest to use the built-in "click text" variable and set a filter "`if click text equals download`" on your link trigger.

Else you might want to try to access the "main.download" attribute. The built-in click element variable returns the clicked DOM element, so you'd create a custom variable

```
function() {
    return {{Click Element}}.getAttribute('ui.sref');
}
```

and then test in your trigger if `"{{your custom js var}} equals main.download"`.

Untested, but basically this should work.